# None of the constructors found can be invoked with the available services and parameters Autofac

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, autofac, autofac-module

I have read and coding follow example: http://timschreiber.com/2015/01/14/persistence-ignorant-asp-net-identity-with-patterns-part-1/
But that example used Unity for DI, but i'm used Autofac for ID, when i try run my project i have the following error:

> None of the constructors found with  'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'App.Front.Controllers.HomeController' can be invoked with the
>   available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2[IdentityStore.IdentityUser,System.Guid]
>   userManager' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2[IdentityStore.IdentityUser,System.Guid])'.

My code:

```
public class IdentityModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //var dbContextParameter = new ResolvedParameter((pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(DbContext),
        //                                               (pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<AppContext>());
        builder.RegisterType<UserStore>().As<IUserStore<IdentityUser, Guid>>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<RoleStore>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

and

```
private static void SetAutofacContainer()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    var mainModules = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().Where(p => p.ManifestModule.Name.StartsWith("App.")).ToArray();
    builder.RegisterControllers(mainModules);
    builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(mainModules);

    builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
    builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());

    builder.RegisterModule(new EFModule());
    builder.RegisterModule(new RepositoryModule());
    builder.RegisterModule(new IdentityModule());
    builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceModule());
    var container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

}
```

Any one help me please!.

Comment: I could really use all of the modules you used to set up Identity via AutoFac. For some reason, my implementation is experiencing the same issue, but I know almost nothing about AutoFac; especially how to set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that *Autofac* can't create an instance of `HomeController` because it can't find its `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<IdentityStore.IdentityUser,System.Guid>
  userManager` parameter.

It seems that this type has not been registered. To solve this error you have to register a `UserManager<IdentityUser, Guid>`. You can do this in your `IdentityModule` class :

```
builder.RegisterType<UserManager<IdentityUser, Guid>>()
       .As<UserManager<IdentityUser, Guid>>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help, my code working now, but i wonder in that example, his code custom UserStore class, if i using your code, my project working now, but when i create and login user my code have an error: [InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.]
My code Signin
 var identity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

Comment: @TrườngSơn I'm not sure to understand. Could you edit your question and explain your issue ?

Comment: I have run into the same problem, but it is complicated by the fact that I am using the MVC HTML5 template, which already includes AutoFac and which doesn’t use OP's pattern. When I try to include the solution from @CyrilDurand it doesn't work. Totally new to DI, completely lost.

Comment: Just register type like me:
 builder.RegisterType<UserManager<IdentityUser, Guid>>()
                .As<UserManager<IdentityUser, Guid>>()
                .InstancePerRequest();